# how to fix a double LEFT JOIN in a trac report

Tags: sql, join, trac

We use a customized version of trac where people can give scores for the bugs based on two criteria, let us call them `severity` and `importance`.

For simplicity, let us say that the database contains the following tables:

Table `ticket`

```
id | title           | reporter
1  | SQL injection   | Torvalds
2  | Buffer Overflow | Linus
3  | Localization    | bofh
```

Table `votes`

```
ticket_id | value | type       | voter
1         | 4     | severity   | Linus
1         | 2     | severity   | Torvalds
1         | 3     | severity   | bofh
1         | 4     | importance | Linus
1         | 3     | importance | Torvalds
2         | 4     | severity   | Linus
2         | 2     | severity   | Torvalds
2         | 1     | importance | Linus
2         | 1     | importance | bofh
3         | 1     | importance | Linus
```

So for instance the first row means that the user `Linus` suggested 4 as the severity score of ticket #1.

Now I have the following SQL query in a trac report that I use to get the average scores:

```
SELECT t.title, t.reporter, AVG(vs.value), AVG(vi.value), COUNT(vs.value), COUNT(vi.value)
FROM ticket t
LEFT JOIN votes vs ON vs.type = 'severity'   AND vs.ticket_id=t.id
LEFT JOIN votes vi ON vi.type = 'importance' AND vi.ticket_id=t.id;
```

In my hopes, this should return a table with the following values:

```
title | reporter | severity avg | importance avg | number of sev. votes | number of imp. votes
SQL injection | Torvalds | 3 | 3.5 | 3 | 2
```

thus telling me how many people voted for the ticket and what their votes are.

However, due to the way `LEFT JOIN` works, the entries that I get are the cartesian product of severity and importance votes, so the averages are still valid, while both counts are set to 3x2=6 instead of the correct value.

Is there a simple way to fix this query, so that it returns what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine CASE statements with aggregate functions:

```
SELECT 
  t.title, 
  t.reporter, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN v.type = 'importance' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_Imp,
  SUM(CASE WHEN v.type = 'severity' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count_Sev,
  SUM(CASE WHEN v.type = 'importance' THEN v.value ELSE 0 END) / 
    Count_Imp AS Avg_Imp,
  SUM(CASE WHEN v.type = 'severity' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 
    Count_Sev AS Avg_Sev
FROM 
  ticket t
  LEFT JOIN votes v 
  ON v.ticket_id = t.id;
```

If Trac SQL doesn't allow you to re-use the aliases `Count_Imp` and `Count_Sev` you would simply repeat those statements in the average calculation columns.

Comment: Thanks! In the end I have solved the issue in a similar way, with a sub-select instead of a LEFT JOIN